# Ubuntu 15.10 & later hard hang during boot from install media

Tags: boot, grub2, 16.04, kernel, 15.10

I have a Shuttle XPC SX58H7 with an Intel Core i7 940 (2.93GHz) processor on which I'm currently running Ubuntu 15.04. In the past I've attempted to upgrade to 15.10, but this failed with a hard hang at some point either during or after the initialization of an I/O APIC. I noticed that if I tried the older 3.19 version Linux kernel, I was able to boot, however, Ubuntu would soon default back to the 4.2 Linux kernel and hard hang again.

I decided to wait for a later version of Ubuntu and try again, hoping that this issue would be investigated and fixed (since it seems to happen far too often).

I don't have any custom drivers and this system runs 15.04 fine, but just can't seem to deal with the 4.2+ Linux kernel. I am no stranger to kernel level programming, having worked on the Windows Kernel team at Microsoft and having developed my own OS kernel from scratch. However, I've taken time off from working to pursue a PhD and am relying on Ubuntu for much of my research since it involves Android.

Since my research project (which I've developed) is now being used by other researchers on varying versions of Ubuntu, I'm hoping to bring my development system up to date with a similar Ubuntu system, however, I'm unable to get past 15.04 (now no longer supported). If I wasn't in my final year and racing to complete my research, I'd probably investigate and fix the Linux kernel issue myself, but I really don't have the luxury of time at the moment.

Does anyone know of any way that I could quickly and easily isolate the problem and workaround it?

**I have no proprietary drivers installed.
Technical information on my system is provided below.**

Thanks in advance!

```
description: Computer

width: 64 bits
capabilities: smbios-2.5 vsyscall32
```

*-core

```
   description: Motherboard
   physical id: 0
 *-memory
      description: System memory
      physical id: 0
      size: 15GiB
 *-cpu
      product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7 CPU         940  @ 2.93GHz
      vendor: Intel Corp.
      physical id: 1
      bus info: cpu@0
      width: 64 bits
      capabilities: fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp x86-64 constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt lahf_lm dtherm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid
 *-pci:0
      description: Host bridge
      product: 5520/5500/X58 I/O Hub to ESI Port
      vendor: Intel Corporation
      physical id: 100
      bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
      version: 13
      width: 32 bits
      clock: 33MHz
    *-pci:0
         description: PCI bridge
         product: 5520/5500/X58 I/O Hub PCI Express Root Port 1
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1
         bus info: pci@0000:00:01.0
         version: 13
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pci msi pciexpress pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=pcieport
         resources: irq:26
    *-pci:1
         description: PCI bridge
         product: 5520/5500/X58 I/O Hub PCI Express Root Port 3
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 3
         bus info: pci@0000:00:03.0
         version: 13
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pci msi pciexpress pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=pcieport
         resources: irq:27
    *-pci:2
         description: PCI bridge
         product: 5520/5500/X58 I/O Hub PCI Express Root Port 7
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 7
         bus info: pci@0000:00:07.0
         version: 13
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pci msi pciexpress pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=pcieport
         resources: irq:28 ioport:e000(size=4096) memory:f9f00000-fbefffff ioport:ce000000(size=301989888)
       *-display
            description: VGA compatible controller
            product: GK106 [GeForce GTX 650 Ti]
            vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
            physical id: 0
            bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
            version: a1
            width: 64 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
            configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
            resources: irq:51 memory:fa000000-faffffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff memory:ce000000-cfffffff ioport:ec00(size=128) memory:f9f80000-f9ffffff
       *-multimedia
            description: Audio device
            product: GK106 HDMI Audio Controller
            vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
            physical id: 0.1
            bus info: pci@0000:05:00.1
            version: a1
            width: 32 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
            configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
            resources: irq:17 memory:fbefc000-fbefffff
    *-generic:0
         description: PIC
         product: 7500/5520/5500/X58 I/O Hub System Management Registers
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 14
         bus info: pci@0000:00:14.0
         version: 13
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pciexpress 8259 cap_list
         configuration: driver=i7core_edac latency=0
         resources: irq:0
    *-generic:1 UNCLAIMED
         description: PIC
         product: 7500/5520/5500/X58 I/O Hub GPIO and Scratch Pad Registers
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 14.1
         bus info: pci@0000:00:14.1
         version: 13
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pciexpress 8259 cap_list
         configuration: latency=0
    *-generic:2 UNCLAIMED
         description: PIC
         product: 7500/5520/5500/X58 I/O Hub Control Status and RAS Registers
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 14.2
         bus info: pci@0000:00:14.2
         version: 13
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pciexpress 8259 cap_list
         configuration: latency=0
    *-generic:3 UNCLAIMED
         description: PIC
         product: 7500/5520/5500/X58 I/O Hub Throttle Registers
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 14.3
         bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
         version: 13
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: 8259
         configuration: latency=0
    *-usb:0
         description: USB controller
         product: 82801JI (ICH10 Family) USB UHCI Controller #4
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1a
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1a.0
         version: 00
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: uhci bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=uhci_hcd latency=0
         resources: irq:16 ioport:9400(size=32)
       *-usbhost
            product: UHCI Host Controller
            vendor: Linux 3.19.0-69-generic uhci_hcd
            physical id: 1
            bus info: usb@3
            logical name: usb3
            version: 3.19
            capabilities: usb-1.10
            configuration: driver=hub slots=2 speed=12Mbit/s
    *-usb:1
         description: USB controller
         product: 82801JI (ICH10 Family) USB UHCI Controller #5
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1a.1
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1a.1
         version: 00
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: uhci bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=uhci_hcd latency=0
         resources: irq:21 ioport:9480(size=32)
       *-usbhost
            product: UHCI Host Controller
            vendor: Linux 3.19.0-69-generic uhci_hcd
            physical id: 1
            bus info: usb@4
            logical name: usb4
            version: 3.19
            capabilities: usb-1.10
            configuration: driver=hub slots=2 speed=12Mbit/s
    *-usb:2
         description: USB controller
         product: 82801JI (ICH10 Family) USB UHCI Controller #6
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1a.2
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1a.2
         version: 00
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: uhci bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=uhci_hcd latency=0
         resources: irq:19 ioport:9800(size=32)
       *-usbhost
            product: UHCI Host Controller
            vendor: Linux 3.19.0-69-generic uhci_hcd
            physical id: 1
            bus info: usb@5
            logical name: usb5
            version: 3.19
            capabilities: usb-1.10
            configuration: driver=hub slots=2 speed=12Mbit/s
    *-usb:3
         description: USB controller
         product: 82801JI (ICH10 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #2
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1a.7
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1a.7
         version: 00
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pm debug ehci bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=ehci-pci latency=0
         resources: irq:18 memory:f9cf8000-f9cf83ff
       *-usbhost
            product: EHCI Host Controller
            vendor: Linux 3.19.0-69-generic ehci_hcd
            physical id: 1
            bus info: usb@1
            logical name: usb1
            version: 3.19
            capabilities: usb-2.00
            configuration: driver=hub slots=6 speed=480Mbit/s
          *-usb
               description: USB hub
               product: HighSpeed Hub
               vendor: NEC Corp.
               physical id: 5
               bus info: usb@1:5
               version: 1.00
               capabilities: usb-2.00
               configuration: driver=hub maxpower=100mA slots=4 speed=480Mbit/s
             *-usb:0
                  description: USB hub
                  product: USB2.0 Hub
                  vendor: VIA Labs, Inc.
                  physical id: 1
                  bus info: usb@1:5.1
                  version: b.e0
                  capabilities: usb-2.10
                  configuration: driver=hub slots=4 speed=480Mbit/s
                *-usb:0
                     description: Keyboard
                     product: Corsair K70 RGB Gaming Keyboard
                     vendor: Corsair
                     physical id: 2
                     bus info: usb@1:5.1.2
                     version: 2.05
                     serial: 1102D02EAE3B9407536FCD02F5001944
                     capabilities: usb-2.00
                     configuration: driver=usbhid maxpower=500mA speed=12Mbit/s
                *-usb:1
                     description: USB hub
                     product: USB2.0 Hub
                     vendor: VIA Labs, Inc.
                     physical id: 4
                     bus info: usb@1:5.1.4
                     version: b.e0
                     capabilities: usb-2.10
                     configuration: driver=hub slots=4 speed=480Mbit/s
                   *-usb
                        description: Keyboard
                        product: Microsoft
                        vendor: Microsoft
                        physical id: 1
                        bus info: usb@1:5.1.4.1
                        version: 2.70
                        capabilities: usb-2.00
                        configuration: driver=usbhid maxpower=500mA speed=12Mbit/s
             *-usb:1
                  description: USB hub
                  vendor: ATEN International Co., Ltd
                  physical id: 4
                  bus info: usb@1:5.4
                  version: 1.00
                  capabilities: usb-1.10
                  configuration: driver=hub maxpower=100mA slots=4 speed=12Mbit/s
                *-usb
                     description: Keyboard
                     product: DVI DL KVMP
                     vendor: ATEN
                     physical id: 1
                     bus info: usb@1:5.4.1
                     version: 1.00
                     capabilities: usb-1.10
                     configuration: driver=usbhid maxpower=100mA speed=12Mbit/s
    *-multimedia
         description: Audio device
         product: 82801JI (ICH10 Family) HD Audio Controller
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1b
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1b.0
         version: 00
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
         resources: irq:50 memory:f9cf4000-f9cf7fff
    *-pci:3
         description: PCI bridge
         product: 82801JI (ICH10 Family) PCI Express Root Port 1
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1c
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.0
         version: 00
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=pcieport
         resources: irq:29 ioport:d000(size=4096) memory:c0000000-c01fffff ioport:c0200000(size=2097152)
       *-ide
            description: IDE interface
            product: JMB368 IDE controller
            vendor: JMicron Technology Corp.
            physical id: 0
            bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
            version: 00
            width: 32 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: ide pm pciexpress bus_master cap_list
            configuration: driver=pata_jmicron latency=0
            resources: irq:16 ioport:dc00(size=8) ioport:d880(size=4) ioport:d800(size=8) ioport:d480(size=4) ioport:d400(size=16)
    *-pci:4
         description: PCI bridge
         product: 82801JI (ICH10 Family) PCI Express Port 2
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1c.1
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.1
         version: 00
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=pcieport
         resources: irq:30 ioport:c000(size=4096) memory:f9e00000-f9efffff ioport:f8f00000(size=1048576)
       *-network
            description: Ethernet interface
            product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
            vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
            physical id: 0
            bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
            logical name: eth0
            version: 02
            serial: 00:30:1b:be:8a:48
            size: 10Mbit/s
            capacity: 1Gbit/s
            width: 64 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
            configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
            resources: irq:32 ioport:c800(size=256) memory:f9eff000-f9efffff memory:f8ff0000-f8ffffff memory:f9ec0000-f9edffff
    *-pci:5
         description: PCI bridge
         product: 82801JI (ICH10 Family) PCI Express Root Port 3
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1c.2
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.2
         version: 00
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=pcieport
         resources: irq:31 ioport:b000(size=4096) memory:f9d00000-f9dfffff ioport:f8e00000(size=1048576)
       *-network
            description: Ethernet interface
            product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
            vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
            physical id: 0
            bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
            logical name: eth1
            version: 02
            serial: 00:30:1b:be:8a:49
            size: 1Gbit/s
            capacity: 1Gbit/s
            width: 64 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
            configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full ip=192.168.1.122 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
            resources: irq:33 ioport:b800(size=256) memory:f9dff000-f9dfffff memory:f8ef0000-f8efffff memory:f9dc0000-f9ddffff
    *-usb:4
         description: USB controller
         product: 82801JI (ICH10 Family) USB UHCI Controller #1
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1d
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.0
         version: 00
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: uhci bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=uhci_hcd latency=0
         resources: irq:23 ioport:9880(size=32)
       *-usbhost
            product: UHCI Host Controller
            vendor: Linux 3.19.0-69-generic uhci_hcd
            physical id: 1
            bus info: usb@6
            logical name: usb6
            version: 3.19
            capabilities: usb-1.10
            configuration: driver=hub slots=2 speed=12Mbit/s
    *-usb:5
         description: USB controller
         product: 82801JI (ICH10 Family) USB UHCI Controller #2
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1d.1
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.1
         version: 00
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: uhci bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=uhci_hcd latency=0
         resources: irq:19 ioport:9c00(size=32)
       *-usbhost
            product: UHCI Host Controller
            vendor: Linux 3.19.0-69-generic uhci_hcd
            physical id: 1
            bus info: usb@7
            logical name: usb7
            version: 3.19
            capabilities: usb-1.10
            configuration: driver=hub slots=2 speed=12Mbit/s
    *-usb:6
         description: USB controller
         product: 82801JI (ICH10 Family) USB UHCI Controller #3
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1d.2
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.2
         version: 00
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: uhci bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=uhci_hcd latency=0
         resources: irq:18 ioport:a000(size=32)
       *-usbhost
            product: UHCI Host Controller
            vendor: Linux 3.19.0-69-generic uhci_hcd
            physical id: 1
            bus info: usb@8
            logical name: usb8
            version: 3.19
            capabilities: usb-1.10
            configuration: driver=hub slots=2 speed=12Mbit/s
    *-usb:7
         description: USB controller
         product: 82801JI (ICH10 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #1
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1d.7
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.7
         version: 00
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pm debug ehci bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=ehci-pci latency=0
         resources: irq:23 memory:f9cfa000-f9cfa3ff
       *-usbhost
            product: EHCI Host Controller
            vendor: Linux 3.19.0-69-generic ehci_hcd
            physical id: 1
            bus info: usb@2
            logical name: usb2
            version: 3.19
            capabilities: usb-2.00
            configuration: driver=hub slots=6 speed=480Mbit/s
    *-pci:6
         description: PCI bridge
         product: 82801 PCI Bridge
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1e
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1e.0
         version: 90
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pci subtractive_decode bus_master cap_list
    *-isa
         description: ISA bridge
         product: 82801JIR (ICH10R) LPC Interface Controller
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1f
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.0
         version: 00
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: isa bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=lpc_ich latency=0
         resources: irq:0
    *-storage
         description: SATA controller
         product: 82801JI (ICH10 Family) SATA AHCI Controller
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1f.2
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.2
         version: 00
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 66MHz
         capabilities: storage msi pm ahci_1.0 bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=ahci latency=0
         resources: irq:34 ioport:a880(size=8) ioport:a800(size=4) ioport:a480(size=8) ioport:a400(size=4) ioport:a080(size=32) memory:f9cfc000-f9cfc7ff
    *-serial UNCLAIMED
         description: SMBus
         product: 82801JI (ICH10 Family) SMBus Controller
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1f.3
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
         version: 00
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         configuration: latency=0
         resources: memory:f9cfe000-f9cfe0ff ioport:400(size=32)
 *-pci:1
      description: Host bridge
      product: Xeon 5500/Core i7 QuickPath Architecture Generic Non-Core Registers
      vendor: Intel Corporation
      physical id: 101
      bus info: pci@0000:ff:00.0
      version: 04
      width: 32 bits
      clock: 33MHz
 *-pci:2
      description: Host bridge
      product: Xeon 5500/Core i7 QuickPath Architecture System Address Decoder
      vendor: Intel Corporation
      physical id: 102
      bus info: pci@0000:ff:00.1
      version: 04
      width: 32 bits
      clock: 33MHz
 *-pci:3
      description: Host bridge
      product: Xeon 5500/Core i7 QPI Link 0
      vendor: Intel Corporation
      physical id: 103
      bus info: pci@0000:ff:02.0
      version: 04
      width: 32 bits
      clock: 33MHz
 *-pci:4
      description: Host bridge
      product: Xeon 5500/Core i7 QPI Physical 0
      vendor: Intel Corporation
      physical id: 104
      bus info: pci@0000:ff:02.1
      version: 04
      width: 32 bits
      clock: 33MHz
 *-pci:5
      description: Host bridge
      product: Xeon 5500/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller
      vendor: Intel Corporation
      physical id: 105
      bus info: pci@0000:ff:03.0
      version: 04
      width: 32 bits
      clock: 33MHz
 *-pci:6
      description: Host bridge
      product: Xeon 5500/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller Target Address Decoder
      vendor: Intel Corporation
      physical id: 106
      bus info: pci@0000:ff:03.1
      version: 04
      width: 32 bits
      clock: 33MHz
 *-pci:7
      description: Host bridge
      product: Xeon 5500/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller Test Registers
      vendor: Intel Corporation
      physical id: 107
      bus info: pci@0000:ff:03.4
      version: 04
      width: 32 bits
      clock: 33MHz
 *-pci:8
      description: Host bridge
      product: Xeon 5500/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller Channel 0 Control Registers
      vendor: Intel Corporation
      physical id: 108
      bus info: pci@0000:ff:04.0
      version: 04
      width: 32 bits
      clock: 33MHz
 *-pci:9
      description: Host bridge
      product: Xeon 5500/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller Channel 0 Address Registers
      vendor: Intel Corporation
      physical id: 109
      bus info: pci@0000:ff:04.1
      version: 04
      width: 32 bits
      clock: 33MHz
 *-pci:10
      description: Host bridge
      product: Xeon 5500/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller Channel 0 Rank Registers
      vendor: Intel Corporation
      physical id: 10a
      bus info: pci@0000:ff:04.2
      version: 04
      width: 32 bits
      clock: 33MHz
 *-pci:11
      description: Host bridge
      product: Xeon 5500/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller Channel 0 Thermal Control Registers
      vendor: Intel Corporation
      physical id: 10b
      bus info: pci@0000:ff:04.3
      version: 04
      width: 32 bits
      clock: 33MHz
 *-pci:12
      description: Host bridge
      product: Xeon 5500/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller Channel 1 Control Registers
      vendor: Intel Corporation
      physical id: 10c
      bus info: pci@0000:ff:05.0
      version: 04
      width: 32 bits
      clock: 33MHz
 *-pci:13
      description: Host bridge
      product: Xeon 5500/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller Channel 1 Address Registers
      vendor: Intel Corporation
      physical id: 10d
      bus info: pci@0000:ff:05.1
      version: 04
      width: 32 bits
      clock: 33MHz
 *-pci:14
      description: Host bridge
      product: Xeon 5500/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller Channel 1 Rank Registers
      vendor: Intel Corporation
      physical id: 10e
      bus info: pci@0000:ff:05.2
      version: 04
      width: 32 bits
      clock: 33MHz
 *-pci:15
      description: Host bridge
      product: Xeon 5500/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller Channel 1 Thermal Control Registers
      vendor: Intel Corporation
      physical id: 10f
      bus info: pci@0000:ff:05.3
      version: 04
      width: 32 bits
      clock: 33MHz
 *-pci:16
      description: Host bridge
      product: Xeon 5500/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller Channel 2 Control Registers
      vendor: Intel Corporation
      physical id: 110
      bus info: pci@0000:ff:06.0
      version: 04
      width: 32 bits
      clock: 33MHz
 *-pci:17
      description: Host bridge
      product: Xeon 5500/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller Channel 2 Address Registers
      vendor: Intel Corporation
      physical id: 111
      bus info: pci@0000:ff:06.1
      version: 04
      width: 32 bits
      clock: 33MHz
 *-pci:18
      description: Host bridge
      product: Xeon 5500/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller Channel 2 Rank Registers
      vendor: Intel Corporation
      physical id: 112
      bus info: pci@0000:ff:06.2
      version: 04
      width: 32 bits
      clock: 33MHz
 *-pci:19
      description: Host bridge
      product: Xeon 5500/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller Channel 2 Thermal Control Registers
      vendor: Intel Corporation
      physical id: 113
      bus info: pci@0000:ff:06.3
      version: 04
      width: 32 bits
      clock: 33MHz
```

Comment: Have you tried 16.04? Chances are it just works.

Comment: I have tried both 16.04 and 16.10, neither work.